# regular expression what does \d+? mean?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regular expression using javascript.

I know \d+ means one or more number(s), but the following ? really confused me! I tried some possibilities:
1.it means zero or more numbers, but /\d+?/.test("a") returns false
2.it means one number followed by zero or one +, but "11+".split(/\d+?/) returns ["","","+"]
(all these codes are in JavaScript)
So it seems like it means exactly one number!?

Thanks for all responses and advice!

Comment: Java != Javascript. This question doesn't involve Java at all.

Comment: You can try this for test your pattern : https://www.debuggex.com/ .
I think that don't change anything.

Comment: @Pufan check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805907/meaning-of-a-regular-expression-d-d

Comment: @Andy absolutely *not*. It means an *ungreedy* one or more numbers.

Comment: Basically, it will always match one number in this case since it's *lazy* (ungreedy). I would just write `/\d/` to clear all confusions.